# Can't find purchased apps in Kubuntu

Tags: software-center, kubuntu, games

I installed Kubuntu 12.04 and am trying to install Humble Bundle through the software center which I installed with the `software-center` package. I see the games on the recently purchased list, they seem to download and install, but after they are installed, I don't see anything in my menu and there is no related executable anywhere in my `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

With Kubuntu you first need to have the **Ubuntu** Software Center installed. Kubuntu uses the Muon Software Center which the Humble Indie Bundle packages are not tied to, however I found a way to get them into Kubuntu.

There is a couple of methods you can try.

The first methos is installing the Ubuntu Software Center in Kubuntu by means of opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center --no-install-recommends
```

This will install the software center properly for you and you have to go to `File -> Reinstall Previously Purchase Software` and use the single sign on to get your list of software.

I posted another method on my personal blog which is way too long to post here but you can look at it by going [here](http://www.gogogeekboy.com/2012/11/install-previously-purchased-sofware-usc-broken/).